# how to show events with its actual time in fullcalendar?

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

I am using jquery fullcalendar resource view in my resource allocation application.

My events time are like this :

```
09:02 to 10:15, 11:00 to 11:30, 13:35 to 14:10 etc.
```

Right now its rounding up the event starttime and end time and displaying on the calendar.

means the `13:35 to 14:10` event is displaying from `13:30 to 14:00`.

But i want to show it with its actual time. like if time slot is `13:00 to 13:30` and event is from `13:35` than it should leave some space and than display it and same like for all.

Is it possible to display like this in jquery fullcalendar ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have a time span more accurate change this option -> [slotMinutes](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/agenda/slotMinutes/)

```
slotMinutes: 1 //1 is one minute so there will be a slot every one minute
```

Comment: ya if i do so than there will be slot for every one min. and i don't want like that. i just need to remove the round timeslot thing.